# Xcode 4: Why do unit tests need their own separate scheme?

Tags: unit-testing, xcode4

I recently downloaded and installed Mac OS X Lion on my Mac Mini.  Soon thereafter I downloaded and installed Xcode 4, and have been proceeding through the tutorials.  So far, so good.

Next I created a new project in Xcode 4 called 'MyApp' and selected the 'Include Unit Tests' option.  I wrote my app and wrote some unit tests, all of which pass.  Yay!

Incredibly, I was able to do all of this without ever once selecting the 'MyAppTests' scheme.  By default, the application 'MyApp' scheme already included a 'Tests' target which correctly references the unit test files.  Furthermore, the Product > Test menu (Command-U) executes those tests from within the 'MyApp' scheme.  The 'MyAppTests' scheme seems completely useless.  In fact, I was able to delete the 'MyAppTests' scheme entirely and nothing broke.

I am surely missing something.  What is this separate 'MyAppTests' scheme used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unit tests don't need a separate scheme, as you discovered. Xcode is initially setup to create a scheme when you create a target. Adding the unit test target added a scheme for the target.

If you don't want Xcode to create a scheme for each new target, choose Manage Schemes from the Scheme menu in the project window toolbar. Deselect the Autocreate schemes checkbox.